# Chaining a Get request from a Post request then sending to client, using Express and Google oauth

Tags: node.js, express, http, google-oauth

I am servicing a Post request, where I retrieve user token id in this request, I further verify the token using OAuth2Client library. When verified, I want  to issue a Get request to get user info. I am not sure of the way I am chaining requests.

Code is like:

```
var userid;
app.post( '/oauth/google/redirect', (req, res) => {
  const token = req.body.idtoken;
  verify().catch(console.error);
  req.get(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=${token}`, (req, res) => {
    var body = "";

      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function() {
        res.send(body)
      });
  })

  });
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');

const client = new OAuth2Client(google.clientID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: google.clientID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //const domain = payload['hd'];
}
```

On client side, browser says it failed on post request as it took too much time returning:

> POST http://mywebapp.com/oauth/google/redirect 504 (Gateway Time-out)

```
Signed in as: <html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I used request as a library, something like:

```
app.post( '/oauth/google/redirect', (req, res) => {
  const token = req.body.idtoken;
  verify().catch(console.error);
  request(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=${token}`, function (error, response, body) {
        var data={
          body:body
        };
        res.send(data);
      });  
  });
```

Still accepting a native Express solution as a better answer.